# Recommended guidance for Blazor task continuation

Tags: task, blazor, continuations

I have a [bad] habit of using .ConfigureAwait(false) when performing any and all async/await calls.

In some cases this is of course good because the vast majority of the time I don't care which thread the code continues on. In some cases I of course need it to continue on the same thread for specific reasons so either I don't use it or make sure the code is on the needed thread.

However, in Blazor does it matter if I call "UI" actions like `StateHasChanged()`  using `InvokeAsync()`?

Does `ConfigureAwait(false)` itself even matter in the context of Blazor server or client-side development?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the guidance is to use it when it is not in the UI context.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13545

Answer (score 1):

You should use (false) when not called from a UI, but when called from within a Blazor component you should use (true) so that continuation code is eventually executed on the sync context.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19004

Comment: And the guideline is to (almost) never use it.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Steve Sanderson from the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13545): `Therefore do not use configureAwait(false) within your Blazor *component* code.`  Note that he says "Component" code (which is interacting with the UI and thus needs to be on the UI Thread.)

But for other code (such as services), it can still be useful. (In other words, Peter Morris's answer should be the accepted answer.)

Furthermore, you can marshal back to the UI thread like this:

`await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`

To explain this concept a little more:

.ConfigureAwait(false) is a hint to .net core that when the awaiting is complete, that the thread does NOT need to be the UI thread. So if you set the parameter to true, or do not use ConfigureAwait() at all, the UI thread is the one which is used to continue the code. This is useful if there is UI activity, such as when calling StateHasChanged which MUST be called from the Ui thread.

If you are doing background work then there is no need to have your code continue on the main thread, as it may be busy doing other things. You can use .ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid any such issues. My personal practice is to always use .ConfigureAwait(false) and if I need to call StateHasChanged, call it using InvokeAsync.  This has worked well for me, but I am going to note that this is only an opinion as I have no real way of measuring the actual results of this.

[This is a .net 8 conference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhCRX3B7qwY) that covers the topic of Async/Await, and talks a lot about ConfigureAwait(false), but note that it is not Blazor specific nor does it even mention Blazor one. But it is excellent for background on what is going on with aysnc/await.

Comment: You might want to point out which link.

Comment: Added the actual link

Comment: The combination `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` adds a little overhead. The general rule (for WinForms, WPF, MAUI, Blazor etc) is to _not_ use it in toplevel code and only use it in services and libraries.